# Changing a column's name to titlecase using dplyr, by means of a function

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the very simple example of renaming the `lat` column of `quakes` to `Lat`, the titlecase version.

```
library(dplyr)

quakes %>%
  rename(Lat = lat)
```

I would like to write this as a function. My attempt so far has been

```
titlecase_col <- function(df, col_name) {
  quakes %>%
    rename(tools::toTitleCase(as_string(ensym(col_name))) := {{col_name}})
}

> titlecase_col(quakes, lat)

Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol
```

The error doesn't make sense to me, since in my mind, that *is* a string, so I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: also this `rename_at(quakes, vars(lat), stringr::str_to_title)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we add the `!!` to evaluate and correct the `syntax errors` (input argument was `df`, whereas inside the function `quakes` was used - it could be a potential bug), it would work

```
titlecase_col <- function(df, col_name) {
  df %>%
    rename(!!tools::toTitleCase(rlang::as_string(ensym(col_name))) 
                  := {{col_name}})
}
```

-testing

```
> titlecase_col(quakes, lat) %>%
     head
     Lat   long depth mag stations
1 -20.42 181.62   562 4.8       41
2 -20.62 181.03   650 4.2       15
3 -26.00 184.10    42 5.4       43
4 -17.97 181.66   626 4.1       19
5 -20.42 181.96   649 4.0       11
6 -19.68 184.31   195 4.0       12
```